# How does the Avatar spell function if my character worships a god that isn't listed under the spell?

Tags: spells, class, religions-and-deities, pathfinder-2e

I'm about to start a 3rd level campaign centered around upper-class intrigue and pirates, so I figured I'd try playing a Cleric of [Ng](https://2e.aonprd.com/Deities.aspx?ID=98) to fit a setting with implicitly ambiguous morals. However, I'm looking both online and in the physical copy I have of *Lost Omens: Gods and Magic* and cannot find any mention of what additional benefits you gain for casting the [**Avatar**](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=16) spell while worshiping this god and its contemporaries in the Eldest Pantheon.

I was ecstatic when I discovered that [Grundinnar](https://2e.aonprd.com/Deities.aspx?ID=88) (the first God I played a Cleric of back in PF1e) was included as a part of the Dwarven Pantheon, but he's in the same boat as the Eldest since the **Avatar** spell does not specify either Grundinnar directly or the Dwarven Pantheon in general.

So my question is **If a Cleric casts the Avatar Spell and their Deity isn't listed under its effect, what happens?**

Comment: I cleaned up some extraneous information; we don't need to know that you have more questions on the way, we just want to help you with your use of the Avatar spell (for now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additional details for casting *Avatar* for different deities other than the core deities in the CRB are found in *Lost Omens: Gods and Magic.* However, I don't believe either Ng or Gundinnar are listed in that level of detail.

Neither receives the same treatment that core deities do (a full page-spread), but both have a listing in the appendix that provides mechanics for a variety of purposes: cleric spells and domains, divine skills and abilities, etc. The details of casting *Avatar* for worshipers of those deities are not described.

Without that level of detail, it's up to your GM to decide what the effects are. They may homebrew some specific bonuses related to your deity, copy one of the existing sets from another deity, or ignore deity-specific bonuses altogether (though that would weaken the spell in our case).